# Self referencing 1 to many relation

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the following entity:

```
 public class TravelCoverageType
 {
     public int Code { get; set; }

     public virtual TravelCoverageType PreventedBy { get; set; }

     public ICollection<TravelCoverageType> PreventCoverages { get; set;}
     ...
 }
```

Each `TravelCoverageType` can prevent 0 or more `TravelCoverageType`s.

I'm using fluent API, but can't figure out how to describe this relation.

I've tried:

```
public TravelCoverageTypeConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable(ConfigConstants.TypeTablePrifix + typeof(TravelCoverageType).Name + "s");
            HasKey(ct => ct.Code);

            HasMany(tc => tc.PreventCoverages)
                .WithOptional(tc=>tc.PreventedBy)
                .HasForeignKey(tc => tc.Code);
        }
```

But I get the following error:

> System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationType: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'TravelCoverageType_PreventCoverages_Source' in relationship 'TravelCoverageType_PreventCoverages'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.
>
> System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'TravelCoverageType_PreventCoverages_Target' in relationship 'TravelCoverageType_PreventCoverages'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.

(I've added `PreventedBy` to make defining the relation simpler, I don't really need it)

How is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be done using the Fluent API? I don't happen to know it so well, but you could do the following with Data Annotations instead:

```
public class TravelCoverageType
{
     [Key]
     public int Code { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("PreventedBy")]
     public int? PreventedByID { get; set; }

     public virtual TravelCoverageType PreventedBy { get; set; }

     public ICollection<TravelCoverageType> PreventCoverages { get; set;}
}
```

EDIT: Looking a little closer at your question, I've noticed that you're trying to have the `Code` property be used as a FK:

```
.HasForeignKey(tc => tc.Code);
```

EF is not liking that at all, for the exception that you're seeing (it's telling you that if you want to make the Primary Key a FK as well that you can only do so for a 1:1, not a 1:Many). Try adding a new property to the class (like I did for the Data Annotations example above), and then change the configuration to this:

```
HasMany(tc => tc.PreventCoverages)
.WithOptional(tc => tc.PreventedBy)
.HasForeignKey(tc => tc.PreventedByID);
```

Comment: That's the standard here :(

Comment: I think the important part here is the nullable foreign key. Your fluent code should work fine if you use that. I have a type called Sections and the follwoing works. HasOptional(section => section.Parent)
                .WithMany(section => section.Sections)
                .HasForeignKey(course => course.ParentId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the PK of your entity as FK too, but you can't do that when you are configuring a one-to-many relationship. If you want to create a self referencing on-to-many relationship and you want to have only a navigation property related to one side of that relationship (I think this is the scenario that you want), your model would be like this:

```
public class TravelCoverageType
{
   public int Code { get; set; }

   public ICollection<TravelCoverageType> PreventCoverages { get; set;}
   ...
}
```

And the the configuration of the relationship would be like this:

```
 HasMany(tc => tc.PreventCoverages).WithOptional();
```

Now, if you want to work with both sides of the relationship, you need to add the `PreventedBy` navigation property as you have in the model that you show. In that case, you can configure the relationship this way:

```
HasMany(tc => tc.PreventCoverages).WithOptional(tc => tc.PreventedBy);
```

Finally, if you want to work with a FK property too, in that case you need to add a another property of the same type of your PK in your entity:

```
public class TravelCoverageType
{
 public int Code { get; set; }

 public int  PreventedById { get; set; }
 public virtual TravelCoverageType PreventedBy { get; set; }

 public ICollection<TravelCoverageType> PreventCoverages { get; set;}
 ...
}
```

and the configuration of your relationship would be like this:

```
HasMany(tc => tc.PreventCoverages).WithOptional(tc => tc.PreventedBy).HasForeignKey(tc=>PreventedById);
```